Calling a python function in javascript? link function in python to be used in my script.js without using flask, but perhaps AJAX?
I have a file recommender.py, which contains a python function get_recommendations(title)
I want to use this in my script.js file
// Function to handle rating submission
function submitRating(movieTitle) {
    const ratingInput = document.getElementById(`rating-${movieTitle}`).value;

    // Store rating in dictionary
    userRatings[movieTitle] = parseFloat(ratingInput);

    // Log userRatings for testing (remove this line in production)
    console.log('User Ratings:', userRatings);
    
    // Call a function to handle further processing (if needed)
    handleRatingSubmission();
}

// Function to handle further processing after rating submission
function handleRatingSubmission() {
    var userRatingsArray = Object.entries(userRatings);

// Sort the array based on the values
    userRatingsArray.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a[1] - b[1]; // Change this if values are not numeric
    });
    console.log(userRatingsArray)
    function getRatingByTitle(title) {
        for (var i = 0; i < userRatingsArray.length; i++) {
            if (userRatingsArray[i][0] === title) {
                return userRatingsArray[i][1];
            }
        }
        // Return null if title not found
        return null;
    }
    var highestmovies = userRatingsArray.slice(0, -2);
    if((getRatingByTitle(highestmovies[1])-getRatingByTitle(highestmovies[0]))>3){
        return get_recommendations(highestmovies[1])
    }
    else{
        var arr1=get_recommendations(highestmovies[1]).splice(0,4)
        var arr2=get_recommendations(highestmovies[0]).splice(0,3)
        arr1= arr1.concat(arr2)
        uniqarr= Array.from(new Set(arr1))
        uniqarr=uniqarr.splice(0,5)
        return uniqarr.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a[1] - b[1]; 
         });
    }

}


I want to use the python get_recommendations function in the Javascript code
How do I go about this? I am not familiar with Javascript at all, any help will be appreciated
I tried to use AJAX request, and converting the entire python code to Javascript but it did not work as expected.
I don't want to use flask, but i am open to it if i know how to go about it, so how do I do this?

The JavaScript code is executed in the browser, while the Python code is on the server. Unless you find a way to transpile your Python in JS, you’ll need a way to communicate between your server and client so that the JS sends the parameters for the function to a server that calls it and responds with its result.
